# How to take a Picture of Ice in Mars Pole?

Tags: popular-science

It is say in other thread, that [impossible to make satellite orbit above of poles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71582/is-it-possible-to-have-a-geostationary-satellite-over-the-poles). But there is a claim from NASA, that in pole of Mars [there is a cap of ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_polar_ice_caps). So they take a picture of it.

How can someone explain this. Is possible to make the satellite that in orbit around equator (geostationer), to change direction and make an orbit around a pole.

Comment: But, satellites aside, we have had pictures of ice on the poles of Mars for years, long before the first space probes: https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/7343/

Answer (score 1):

The question you link to asks about why it is not possible for a *geostationary* satellite to be over the poles.  Satellites can pass over the poles, they just cannot remain there.  But they can certainly be near or over the poles and can take photographs as they do.

Unless the satellite that took the photograph was described as geostationary, there is no contradiction.

Comment: Well, [areostationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areostationary_orbit), but you've gotten the idea across.